# Python summing dataframe columns resulting in wrong output

Tags: python, pandas, sum, floating-point

I am coding a python app which uses dataframes and I have few columns that has "amount of money" as data. For instance values like 2148.38.

the issues I have is that at some point I have to sum up the whole column but I have a different result than the one I have in my excel (which contains the "ground truth value"). I tried different solution and at some point i even created a list containing all the excels values of this column, and then compared them to the one obtained with python. Guess what, they are all exactly correct but once again when summing them it result in wrong output.

As I thought this could be due to floating point operations, I tried multiplying all the values by 100 and converting them to int. But even like this, it doesn't work. Do you have any idea ?

Here are my tries

```
res = annuities['PV of annuity'].sum()
```

```
res = 0
for i in range(len(annuities)):
    res += int(annuities.loc[i,'PV of annuity']*100)
res
```

both computation gives gives  351571.42000000004

```
np.sum((annuities['PV of annuity']*100).astype(int))
```

gives 35157118 and the correct output should be 351571.35

And note that I obtain different result for all three of them (there are a few cents difference)

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you add to your post the different results you get ?

Comment: Is your excel values are really `2148.38` or is it possible that's only the display with 2 digits after the decimal point ? Is your excel sum always bigger than your pandas ? Also, interesting reading : https://jimmy-shen.medium.com/python-floating-number-sum-give-different-result-ac6f60f52a1f

Comment: excel is indeed displaying only 2 digit but it's because in the formula, all computations are rounded to 2 digits, just as I did in my code

Comment: Also I had some struggle having a good rounding function but now it works and I have implemented a lot of other computations using also those columns and they are correct.

Comment: What is weird is that I just implemented another thing, which uses another vector and I also do the sum but the result is correct...

Comment: If you're working with monetary values, you should consider using ints instead of floats.